# What values can take errno

Tags: linux, errno

What values ​​can take errno? At what minimum largest type variables can I store the value errno?

Answer (score 0):

Posix requires `errno` to be equivalent to `int`:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/xsh_chap02_03.html

> The symbol errno, defined by including the  header, expands
>   to a modifiable lvalue of type int. It is unspecified whether errno is
>   a macro or an identifier declared with external linkage. If a macro
>   definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a
>   program defines an identifier with the name errno, the behavior is
>   undefined.